# PHP Array conditions not working

Tags: php, arrays

Still learning PHP etc... im getting an error on the following:

```
'payment_status'    => ( 'P' == $order_info['status'] || 'C' == $order_info['status'] || 'O' == $order_info['status'] ) ? 'paid' : 'paid' : 'unpaid',
```

which is from part of my array but is giving an error at that line...

First attempt at this kind of condition within an array so was likely would of broke but in case dont know what i was aiming for...

> if order_info status = P to set paid
>
> if order_info status = C to set paid
>
> if order_info status = O to set unpaid

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem in this case was obvious, but don't forget to mention the error message you get: it's helpful. Really :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have too many `: 'paid'`s.

Change the end to this:

`? 'paid' : 'unpaid'`

You could also make this a bit more readable:

```
$paid_statuses = array('P', 'C'); // O is unpaid
...
'payment_status' => (in_array($order_info['status'], $paid_statuses) ? 'paid' : 'unpaid')`
```

Comment: Was answering at the same time... :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, so something like this will work? http://pastebin.com/CfknYYCd

Comment: Super, not getting error now so fixed... now for testing :) thanks for the help.